# Issue with a tooltip not always displayed on screen

Tags: html, css

The issue is that my tooltip is not always **completely** on my screen. If my div is on the top of my screen my tooltip is trunked.

JSP page:

```
    <div onmouseover="hideElementsByClassName('tooltip');displayElementById('toolip-42');" onmouseleave="hideElementById('toolip-42')">
        <img src="IMG/bouton/test.png">
        <div id="toolip-42" class="toolip" style="display: none;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
                <table>
                    ...
                    ...
                </table>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

tooltip CSS:

```
.tooltip {  
    width: 800px;   
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid #C3C3C3;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -455px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

What I expect is for my tooltip to always stay on the right of my image `<img>` but never trunked from the screen :

- When I'm on the top of my screen tooltip should be displayed on the
  middle-bottom of my image.
- When I'm on the middle of my screen tooltip should be displayed on
  the middle on my screen.
- When I'm on the bottom of my screen tooltip should be displayed on
  the middle-top of my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the solution with JS :

```
function customDisplayElementById(eltId){
       var elt = document.getElementById(eltId);
        if(elt != null ){           
            elt.style.display= "";      
            elt.style['margin-top'] = -108 + 'px';// 108 height of div element
            var elmt = this.getOffset(elt);
            if(window.scrollY+window.innerHeight < elmt.bottom ){
                //console.log('popup trop bas');
                elt.style['margin-top'] = -1*(elmt.height-3) + 'px';
            }
            //console.log('elmt.left : ' + elmt.left + '\n','elmt.right : ' + elmt.right + '\n','elmt.top :' + elmt.top+ '\n','elmt.bottom : ' + elmt.bottom + '\n','elmt.width : ' + elmt.width + '\n','elmt.height : ' + elmt.height + '\n','window.screenY : '+ window.screenY);
        }
   }

  function getOffset(el) {
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
            top: rect.top + window.scrollY,
            right: rect.right + window.scrollX,
            bottom: rect.bottom + window.scrollY,
            width : rect.width,
            height : rect.height
        };
    }
```

change the div onmouseover method with :

```
<div onmouseover="customDisplayElementById('toolip-42'); onmouseleave="hideElementById('toolip-42')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you can use the 'title' attribute to display tooltips?

```
<div title="Hey there!">Hellow world</div>
```

It will sort out the positioning automatically.

Comment: As we can see on the uploaded image the tooltip isn't just a simple display of text 
It's a table with a lot of text and img and files.